# redirect output from one function to another

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a pipeline from user input, but when I redirect the output I'm getting a output with no newlines and it's just one huge single line.Here's the code :

```
 42 function stack(){
 43  echo $(history|tail -1|cut -d" " -f5-|cut -d "|" -f1) >> ~/commands
 44  local last=$(tail -1 ~/commands)
 45  echo  $(eval $last) >> ~/output
 46 }
```

Is there a better way to pipe the output from this to a file ? Echo seems to corrupt the output.

Comment: Why `echo $(eval $last)` ? Why not just `eval $last`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the purpose of cuts, but quote are missing around `$()` so the output is split into words with IFS

```
echo "$(eval "$last")"
```

maybe `cut -c8-` is safer than `cut -d" " -f5-` for history entries with a number with number of digits different from 3.

also `cut -d"|" -f1` can fail if `|` is used as literal for example `echo '|'`.

Maybe you can look at `Even designators` in bash manual : in interactive bash following will run the last command

```
$ !-1
```

Comment: it can work in interactive bash only and can't be used in functions because expansion occurs at function definition